# Is there a better way to implement this scrolling gallery so that it doesn't break when clicking the arrow multiple times quickly

Tags: javascript, velo

I created a scrolling gallery that works as intended, but when you repeatedly press the arrow quickly, it breaks down.
It will recover when you stop, but I would like it more fluid when it is pressed quickly.

```
const options = {
    slideOptionsRight: {
        "duration": 1000, //Change how quickly the picture fades in milliseconds.
        "direction": "right"
    },
    slideOptionsLeft: {
        "duration": 1000,
        "direction": "left"
    },
    images: [ //Add image names to be added to the scroll here, wrapped in quotation marks.
        '#image1',
        '#image2',
        "#image3",
        "#image6"
    ],
    arrowImage: [ //Add arrow images here.
        "#image4", //Left arrow.
        "#image5" //Right arrow.
    ],
    "interval": 3, //Change time between pictures in seconds.
    "imageArray": 0,
    "timer": 0,
    "leftClick": false,
    "clicked": false
}

//Does not need to be touched or changed
$w.onReady(function () {
    for (let i = 1; i < options.images.length; i++) {
        $w(options.images[i]).hide()
    }

    const changePicture = () => {
        options.timer += 1;
        if (options.timer > options.interval || options.clicked) {
            if (options.leftClick) {
                if (options.imageArray === 0) {
                    options.images.forEach((e) => {
                        $w(e).hide("slide", options.slideOptionsRight)
                    })
                    // $w(options.images[0]).hide("slide", options.slideOptionsRight);
                    $w(options.images[options.images.length - 1]).show("slide", options.slideOptionsLeft);
                    options.imageArray = options.images.length - 1;
                } else {
                    options.images.forEach((e) => {
                        $w(e).hide("slide", options.slideOptionsRight)
                    })
                    // $w(options.images[options.imageArray]).hide("slide", options.slideOptionsRight);
                    $w(options.images[options.imageArray - 1]).show("slide", options.slideOptionsLeft);
                    options.imageArray -= 1;
                }
                options.leftClick = false;
            } else {
                if (options.imageArray === options.images.length - 1) {
                    options.images.forEach((e) => {
                        $w(e).hide("slide", options.slideOptionsLeft)
                    })
                    // $w(options.images[options.imageArray]).hide("slide", options.slideOptionsLeft);
                    $w(options.images[0]).show("slide", options.slideOptionsRight);
                    options.imageArray = 0;
                } else {
                    options.images.forEach((e) => {
                        $w(e).hide("slide", options.slideOptionsLeft)
                    })
                    // $w(options.images[options.imageArray]).hide("slide", options.slideOptionsLeft);
                    $w(options.images[options.imageArray + 1]).show("slide", options.slideOptionsRight);
                    options.imageArray += 1;
                }
            }
            options.timer = 0
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    let startInterval = setInterval(changePicture, 1000)

    $w(options.arrowImage[1]).onClick(() => {
        options.clicked = true;
        changePicture();
        options.clicked = false;
    })

    $w(options.arrowImage[0]).onClick(() => {
        options.leftClick = true;
        options.clicked = true;
        changePicture();
        options.leftClick = false;
        options.clicked = false;
    })
});
```

Is there a way to force the slide effect to complete early, or would a complete different implementation be better?

link to a test https://joshsetterstrom.wixsite.com/mysite

Comment: You sent the arrow a lot of unsolicited email? ;) Sounds like you need to look into "debouncing".

Comment: I now see how spam was not the right word to use...
I was considering debouncing, but then it doesn't act the way I would like it to; I want to be able to scroll through the pictures quickly.

Comment: Oh, you can ignore me about word choices; I'm old and set in my words :). Most debouncing routines allow you to set a time value that you can tweak to get the responsiveness you want. Anyway, just a thought (hence a comment, not an answer).

Comment: have you tried putting a `stop()` before your animations - this will stop the previous one before starting the next one so you don't get lots of them overlapping if you click the button quickly - not sure if it works with the jquery ui version of show though

Comment: The create thing with this Wix site, is that it is very limited in what you can do...
I cannot add a `stop()`, unfortunately.